# Action cable: How to broadcast the chat messages only the specific chat room in Rails 5?

Tags: angularjs, websocket, chat, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I currently have a Rails 5 application acting as my back-end,we can call this the "Core." I also have another Angular 1.6.4 application  acting as my front-end, which is serving up Angular client side,And integrate with backed-end application through angular-actionable  we can call this the "Front". These are two completely separate applications with completely different domains.

Basically, I am trying to integrate Action Cable through the Core and have it talk to the Front. I'm using this service here for the Front: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Neil-Ni/rails5-actioncable-angular-demo/tree/master/server/app). As far as the Core, that's just basic Action Cable set up.

I have a list of chat rooms on admin side.

Problem: I sent message from client side but it broadcast message to all the chat rooms in admin side.I try to give the specific path of chat room in stream but still it broadcast message to all chat rooms.

I want to broadcast the message to specific **chat room**

**Core**

**chat_channel.rb**

```
class ChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
   def subscribed
      stream_from stream_name
   end
   def unsubscribed
     stop_all_streams
   end

   def receive(data)
       ActionCable.server.broadcast stream_name,  data.fetch('message')
   end

   private

   def stream_name
      "chat_channel_#{chat_id}"
   end

   def chat_id
      params.fetch('data').fetch('chat')
   end
end
```

**Fornt**

**chatCtrl.js**

```
app.run(function (ActionCableConfig){
   ActionCableConfig.debug = true;
   ActionCableConfig.wsUri= "ws://localhost:3000/cable";
});
app.controller('chatCtrl', ['$scope', 'ActionCableChannel',
function($scope, ActionCableChannel) {

  var consumer = new ActionCableChannel("ChatChannel", { chat: 'localhost:3000/#!/chat/1'});
  var callback = function(message) {
    $scope.myData.push(message);
  };
  consumer.subscribe(callback).then(function(){
    $scope.sendToMyChannel = function(message){
      consumer.send(message);
    };
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function(){
      consumer.unsubscribe().then(function(){ $scope.sendToMyChannel = undefined; });
    });
  });
}
]);
```

Comment: I edit this post please see it if you want further info tell me. Basically i want how to send the **chatroom_id ** during broadcast the message, so that it will broadcast the message to specific chat room ????

Answer (score 1):

this is the solution for my problem, very similar to yours, but I did not use cofeescript, just javascript.. so I attach also my code if you need it.. I just check that the attribute `data-chat-room-id` from the DOM is equal to the one I am passing with the message:

The message controller create the message then with `ActionCable.server.broadcast` calls with those parameters (message, user, chatroom_id, lastuser) my js code in messages.js

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    message = Message.new(message_params)
    message.user = current_user
    chatroom = message.chatroom
    if message.save
        ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages',
        message: message.content,
        user: message.user.name,
        chatroom_id: message.chatroom_id,
        lastuser: chatroom.messages.last(2)[0].user.name
      head :ok
    end
  end
end
```

Inside `app/assets/javascrips/channels/messages.js` I do a check that `data.chatroom_id` (the element from the DOM) equals `chat_room_id` (the element sent from the controller, of the object message just saved)

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessagesChannel', {      
  received: function(data) {
    messages = $('#chatroom_id');
    chat_room_id = messages.data('chat-room-id');
    if (data.chatroom_id == chat_room_id) {
      $('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data));
      };
  },
  renderMessage: function(data) {
      return "<br><p> <strong>" + data.user + ": </strong>" + data.message + "</p>";
  }
});
```

This is the article that gave me this answer

[Action Cable chat Ilya Bodrov-Krukowski](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-a-chat-app-with-rails-5-actioncable-and-devise/)

Ilya Bodrov-Krukowski on [Github](https://github.com/bodrovis)

> Another problem to tackle here is providing our script with the room’s id. Let’s solve it with the help of HTML data- attribute:
>
> views/chat_rooms/show.html.erb

```
<div id="messages" data-chat-room-id="<%= @chat_room.id %>">
  <%= render @chat_room.messages %>
</div>
```

> Having this in place, we can use room’s id in the script:
>
> javascripts/channels/rooms.coffee

```
jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  messages = $('#messages')
  if $('#messages').length > 0

    App.global_chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
        channel: "ChatRoomsChannel"
        chat_room_id: messages.data('chat-room-id')
      },
      connected: ->
        # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

      disconnected: ->
        # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

      received: (data) ->
        # Data received

      send_message: (message, chat_room_id) ->
        @perform 'send_message', message: message, chat_room_id: chat_room_id
```